# Creating Redundent Share Folders accessed by single host name

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, group-policy

Alright, in an effort to increase redundency I am trying to share one folder one 3 different servers and be able to access each of them from a single hostname.

What I am trying to do.
Host a shared folder "logon" on each of my domain controllers and have them accessible via a single hostname. That way if any two of the three domain contollers go down the folder is still accessible from the single host name. This name will only be used to host logon scripts and full certain files used by Group Policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any extra hardware, you can setup a DNS Round robin to point a hostname to the 3 different servers. The issue with this is that if one of the servers goes down, there's still a chance the DNS round robin will point a user to the dead server and still cause issues

With extra hardware, you could setup a load balancer that you can assign a hostname to.
The load balancer will then take care of palming off requests to the right servers, and if one of the servers goes down, the load balancer will not palm off requests to the dead server.

Answer (score 2):

DFS (Distributed File System) is perfect for this.  In fact it is what AD domain controllers use to present a single "share" that is distributed among several servers such that if one goes down, the share is still accessible by clients still using the same name.  Such as SYSVOL.  Nothing is stopping you from making your own DFS share that works just like SYSVOL does.  It also had the added bonus of referring clients to the proper host depending on their geographical location (assuming you have your AD Sites set up correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the files in the NETLOGON share on your domain controllers (which is where legacy logon scripts typically go) and let DFS-R handle the replication. You've then killed two birds with one stone.